# How to redirect to success page from controller

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, order-success-page, place-order

This is my controller page. I need to redirect to success page and place all orders in cart. This returns https 500 error.

```
<?php

namespace Cod\Otp\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class sotp extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $cartManagement;
    protected $quote;
    protected $resultRedirect;
    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagement,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultPageFactory

        ){
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->cartManagement = $cartManagement;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->resultRedirect = $context->getResultFactory();
            $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
        $this->quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $this->quote->getPayment()->setMethod('payfull');
        $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($this->quote->getId());
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/onepage/success', ['_secure' => true]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> First thing your class name should start with Capital letter

**By the following code you can redirect to the success page**

```
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/onepage/success');
return $resultRedirect;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
/** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
           $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
           return $resultRedirect->setPath('router_id/controller_name/action_name');
```